# Are Etingof and Serre the only books to discuss representation theory of semidirect product?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters, semidirect-product

I have found discussions about the representation theory of semidirect products in the Section 4.26 of [Introduction to Representation Theory](http://bookstore.ams.org/stml-59/) by Etingof et al and Section 8.2 of [Linear Representations of Finite Groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387901906) by Serre.

I am also aware of the discussion on the representation theory of wreath product in the context of nonabelian groups in the Chapter 4 of [The Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group](https://www.scribd.com/doc/97342424/James-Kerber-Representation-Theory-of-Symmetric-Groups) by James and Kerber.

Is there any other book which discusses the representation theory of semidirect product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that [Elements of the Representation Theory of the Jacobi Group](http://www.springer.com/in/book/9783034802826) also deals with sufficient depth on the topics. Also a section called "[The Mackey analogy and K-theory](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=t8EbCAAAQBAJ&dq=representation+theory+of+semidirect+product&source=gbs_navlinks_s)" sheds some light on the discussion.

However, I did find PDFs on the subject:

$(1)$ [The Journal of London Math Society](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-13/2/281.extract).
$(2)$ [Science Direct](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123675900622).

Hope it helps.